# Lubuntu, Sony HDTV as monitor, text display issues. Please help!

Tags: lubuntu, display, sony, tv

earlier today I set up my Sony TV to be my monitor. When I did, I just disconnected my normal monitor and plugged right into my tv. Everything was fine when I did that.
But then I reset my computer and all of a sudden all of the text and window borders became super small.
I've looked around for a fix and although I've seen some posts about it, I couldn't wrap my head around how to fix it.
Could someone walk me through getting this fixed? I would really like to keep this as my monitor.

Comment: I found how to make the system fonts larger but the font of my applications is still super tiny (audacious, xterminal. ect)
What do I have to do to fix that? :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have found at least one of the system fonts settings, but I have found at least 3 on my installation (Lubuntu 14.04).

From the launcher button:
1. Preferences - Customise Look and Feel, then on the Widget tab there is a default font.
2. Preferences - Desktop Preferences, then on the Appearance tab there is a label text font.
3. Preferences - Openbox Configuration Manager, then on the Appearance page there are 6 fonts to set.

You might also want to right-click on the panel (i.e. the bar with the icons, clock, power icon etc.) and select Panel Settings. On the Geometry tab increase the height and icon size.

Unfortunately I cannot find out how to change the font sizes for audacious and xterminal, but some applications do let you change the font size. I usually use LXTerminal instead of XTerm, and LXTerminal does allow you to change the font size in Edit - Preferences.

Also make sure the screen resolution (Preferences - Monitor Settings) is set to a resolution that your screen supports. There is no point in using a resolution higher than what your TV can do. In the specification section towards the rear of the TV manual (Sony do supply TV manuals online if you don't have it. I know this because I have downloaded one for the very same reason. Google the TV make and model number) you should be able to find the highest supported resolution.

If you do change the resolution, you may also want to change the resolution of the login screen. You do this by editing the xorg.conf file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. You will need to create this if you don't already have it with the following commands:
    sudo service lightdm stop
    sudo Xorg -configure
    sudo mv xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
    #Edit the xorg.conf file with your editor of choice
    sudo service lightdm start

You will want to find Section "Screen", scroll down to the last "EndSubSection" before the "EndSection" and insert the line:
`Modes     "1360x768"`
before the "EndSubSection" line.
(You input your desired resolution instead of "1360x768" if it is different)

Another option to make everything readable is that you set your resolution very low, but this would defeat the purpose of the HD in your TV. However, it may make things easier temporarily while you try to read menu options.